# WebView "Press again to exit" Toast message not working on home page

Tags: webview, android-toast

I need some help regarding eCommerce WebView app that I have created in Android Studio and this App is related to online e-store.

Required a correct code for toast message "Press again to exit" should show on home screen only. I have written a code in android studio as given below, but the toast "Press again to exit" message is showing on all web pages except home page. When I pressed mobile back button on home page the App is getting closed without showing toast and it is showing after app closed. Below is my code:

```js
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
  if (webView.canGoBack()) 
  {
    webView.goBack();
  } 
    else 
    {
      super.onBackPressed();
    }

  if (doubleTap) 
  {
    super.onBackPressed();
  } 
    else 
    {
      Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
      toast.show();
      webView.getUrl();
      doubleTap = true;
      Handler handler = new Handler();
      handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
      {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
          doubleTap = false;
        }
      }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Hope, I get a solution for this and thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution myself after a long time with spending lot of reprogramming my code. Hope this helpful who are looking for same code for WebView app.

Here is the code:

```js
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
  if (webView.canGoBack()) 
  {
    webView.goBack();
  } 
  else if (doubleTap) 
  {
    super.onBackPressed();
  } 
    else 
    {
      Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
      toast.show();
      doubleTap = true;
      Handler handler = new Handler();
      handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
      {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
          doubleTap = false;
        }
      }, 2000);
    }
}
```